# ffmpeg Unsupported codec adpcm_ima_wav when i want sending in RTP

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, adpcm

when i want encode a wav file and send it with rtp in ffmpeg i receive an error that say "Unsupported codec adpcm_ima_wav" but i can encode this file with adpcm_ima_wav and save this file but i can not send with rtp in ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -re -thread_queue_size 4 -i audio -acodec adpcm_ima_wav -sdp_file test.sdp  -f rtp "rtp://127.0.0.1:2222"
```

below show this error:

```
Input #0, wav, from 'audio':
  Metadata:
    encoded_by      : Pro Tools
    originator_reference: !jtMVHCThOfaaaGk
    date            : 2010-09-14
    creation_time   : 08:04:58
    time_reference  : 0
  Duration: 00:00:30.03, bitrate: 2304 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s24le (native) -> adpcm_ima_wav (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtp @ 0x55867efcd380] Unsupported codec adpcm_ima_wav
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg Support decode and encode adpcm_ima_wav but When you want to convert any codec to adpcm_ima_wav,chunk is important for you so you need to pay attentions to calculation of chunk. I understood that i forgot calculation chunk of That voice i want to convert.